# Issue using instagram-node

Tags: node.js, instagram

I get an issue using the module Instagram-node, I'm not able to get all the medias... There is a limit and I don't want this limit, I want to get all the medias of the current user...

My code :

```
    self.api.user_media_recent(userId, function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit){
      console.log(medias.length); // only 35... should be 200 or something like that...
      medias.forEach( function(media){
        var url = media.images.thumbnail.url;
      });
      response.render('home/photos', {medias: medias, type: request.query.state});
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [documenation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-node#readme), the result is paginated, you need to do the following:

```
var hdl = function(err, result, pagination, remaining, limit) {
  // Your implementation here
  if(pagination.next) {
    pagination.next(hdl); // Will get second page results
  }
};

ig.tag_media_recent('test', hdl);
```